# Visual Studio C++ LNK1104: Cannot open file pthreadsVC2.lib, despite removing dependency from linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, linker

A couple months ago I did a project in C++ with Visual Studio that I needed pthreads for, so I installed the library, added it in the linker, etc. and it worked. I just started a new project on this computer for the first time since then that doesn't need pthreads. When I tried to compile this project, it gave me an error because it couldn't find the pthread library file. So I went to the linker, saw the pthread library in it, and thus removed it. However, I still get a compile error because it can't find the pthread library, even though I've searched through the project and can find no reference to needing pthread.

[image: My empty linker input.]

Answer (score 0):

Do a full rebuild.

The MSVC build process embeds library references in the generated obj files. The usual partial build does not remove those files and so the references are still there despite being removed from the project settings.

Comment: The same error occurred whenever I did rebuild, both for solution and project, and even when creating another whole new project.